# Firebase Banner Ad not loading

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've implemented Firebase and originally had ad banners loading fine.  But at some point along the way they have stopped showing up and i've tried everything i can think of.  I have no idea what i could have changed as not much is different and certainly nothing with the Firebase or AdMob code has changed.

```
print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-6956068899232786/3635179951"
bannerView.rootViewController = self
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
bannerView.loadRequest(request)
```

I have also tried implementing the `adViewDidReceiveAd()` delegate function and i'm not seeing that get called either.

Comment: can you upload logs?

Comment: I ended up just removing the banner view and creating a new one and re-doing the code from scratch.  That worked.  So i'm not sure what it was, but @gordin.mitya was correct as to the delegate declaration.

Answer (score 3):

adViewDidReceiveAd did not call because you forget add

```
bannerView.delegate = self
```